# Lifetime constraints to model scoped garbage collection

Tags: garbage-collection, rust, lifetime

I'm working with a friend to define a safe public API for lifetimes of a "scoped" garbage collector. The lifetimes are either overly constrained and correct code does not compile or the lifetimes are too loose and they may allow invalid behavior. After trying multiple approaches, we are still stuck getting a correct API. This is especially frustrating because Rust's lifetimes can help avoid bugs in this situation but right now it just looks stubborn.

## Scoped garbage collection

I am implementing an ActionScript interpreter and need a garbage collector. I studied [rust-gc](https://github.com/Manishearth/rust-gc) but it did not suit my needs. The main reason is that it requires the garbage collected values to have [a static lifetime](https://github.com/Manishearth/rust-gc/blob/e362a0687260534305b2749f986da3f0df1ec356/gc/src/gc.rs#L79) because the GC state is a thread-local static variable. I need to get garbage-collected bindings to a dynamically created host object. The other reason to avoid globals is that it is easier for me to handle multiple independent garbage-collected scopes, control their memory limits or serialize them.

A scoped garbage collector is similar to a [typed-arena](https://github.com/SimonSapin/rust-typed-arena). You can use it to allocate values and they are all freed once the garbage collector is dropped. The difference is that you can also trigger garbage collection during its lifetime and it will clean-up the unreachable data (and is not limited to a single type).

I have [a working implementation implemented (mark & sweep GC with scopes)](https://github.com/open-flash/rust-scoped-gc/tree/master/scoped-gc/src), but the interface is not yet safe to use.

Here is a usage example of what I want:

```
pub struct RefNamedObject<'a> {
    pub name: &'a str,
    pub other: Option<Gc<'a, GcRefCell<NamedObject<'a>>>>,
}

fn main() {
    // Initialize host settings: in our case the host object will be replaced by a string
    // In this case it lives for the duration of `main`
    let host = String::from("HostConfig");

    {
        // Create the garbage-collected scope (similar usage to `TypedArena`)
        let gc_scope = GcScope::new();

        // Allocate a garbage-collected string: returns a smart pointer `Gc` for this data
        let a: Gc<String> = gc_scope.alloc(String::from("a")).unwrap();

        {
            let b = gc_scope.alloc(String::from("b")).unwrap();
        }

        // Manually trigger garbage collection: will free b's memory
        gc_scope.collect_garbage();

        // Allocate data and get a Gc pointer, data references `host`
        let host_binding: Gc<RefNamed> = gc_scope
            .alloc(RefNamedObject {
                name: &host,
                other: None,
            })
            .unwrap();

        // At the end of this block, gc_scope is dropped with all its
        // remaining values (`a` and `host_bindings`)
    }
}
```

## Lifetime properties

The basic intuition is that `Gc` can only contain data that lives as long (or longer) than the corresponding `GcScope`. `Gc` is similar to `Rc` but supports cycles. You need to use `Gc<GcRefCell<T>>` to mutate values (similar to `Rc<RefCell<T>>`).

Here are the properties that must be satisfied by the lifetimes of my API:

### `Gc` cannot live longer than its `GcScope`

The following code must **fail** because `a` outlives `gc_scope`:

```
let a: Gc<String>;
{
    let gc_scope = GcScope::new();
    a = gc_scope.alloc(String::from("a")).unwrap();
}
// This must fail: the gc_scope was dropped with all its values
println("{}", *a); // Invalid
```

### `Gc` cannot contain data that lives shorter than its `GcScope`

The following code must **fail** because `msg` does not live as long (or longer) as `gc_scope`

```
let gc_scope = GcScope::new();
let a: Gc<&string>;
{
    let msg = String::from("msg");
    a = gc.alloc(&msg).unwrap();
}
```

### It must be possible to allocate multiple `Gc` (no exclusion on `gc_scope`)

The following code must compile

```
let gc_scope = GcScope::new();

let a = gc_scope.alloc(String::from("a"));
let b = gc_scope.alloc(String::from("b"));
```

### It must be possible to allocate values containing references with lifetimes longer than `gc_scope`

The following code must compile

```
let msg = String::from("msg");
let gc_scope = GcScope::new();
let a: Gc<&str> = gc_scope.alloc(&msg).unwrap();
```

### It must be possible to create cycles of Gc pointers (that's the whole point)

Similarly to the `Rc<Refcell<T>>` pattern, you can use `Gc<GcRefCell<T>>` to mutate values and create cycles:

```
// The lifetimes correspond to my best solution so far, they can change
struct CircularObj<'a> {
    pub other: Option<Gc<'a, GcRefCell<CircularObj<'a>>>>,
}

let gc_scope = GcScope::new();

let n1 = gc_scope.alloc(GcRefCell::new(CircularObj { other: None }));
let n2 = gc_scope.alloc(GcRefCell::new(CircularObj {
    other: Some(Gc::clone(&n1)),
}));
n1.borrow_mut().other = Some(Gc::clone(&n2));
```

## Solutions so far

### Automatic lifetime / lifetime tag

Implemented on the [`auto-lifetime` branch](https://github.com/open-flash/rust-scoped-gc/blob/auto-lifetime/scoped-gc/src/gc_scope.rs)

This solution is inspired by [`neon`](https://github.com/neon-bindings/neon)'s handles.
This lets any valid code compile (and allowed me to test my implementation) but is too loose and allows invalid code. **It allows `Gc` to outlive the `gc_scope` that created it**. (Violates the first property)

The idea here is that I add a single lifetime `'gc` to all my structs. The idea is that this lifetime represents "how long gc_scope lives".

```
// A smart pointer for `T` valid during `'gc`
pub struct Gc<'gc, T: Trace + 'gc> {
    pub ptr: NonNull<GcBox<T>>,
    pub phantom: PhantomData<&'gc T>,
    pub rooted: Cell<bool>,
}
```

I call it automatic lifetimes because the methods never mix these struct lifetimes with the lifetime of the references they receive.

Here is the impl for gc_scope.alloc:

```
impl<'gc> GcScope<'gc> {
    // ...
    pub fn alloc<T: Trace + 'gc>(&self, value: T) -> Result<Gc<'gc, T>, GcAllocErr> {
        // ...
    }
}
```

### Inner/outer lifetimes

Implemented on the [`inner-outer` branch](https://github.com/open-flash/rust-scoped-gc/blob/inner-outer/scoped-gc/src/gc_scope.rs)

This implementation tries to fix the previous issue by relating `Gc` to the lifetime of `GcScope`. **It is overly constrained and prevents the creation of cycles.** This violates the last property.

To constrain `Gc` relative to its `GcScope`, I introduce two lifetimes: `'inner` is the lifetime of `GcScope` and the result is `Gc<'inner, T>`. `'outer` represents a lifetime longer than `'inner` and is used for the allocated value.

Here is the alloc signature:

```
impl<'outer> GcScope<'outer> {
    // ...

    pub fn alloc<'inner, T: Trace + 'outer>(
        &'inner self,
        value: T,
    ) -> Result<Gc<'inner, T>, GcAllocErr> {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

### Closure (context management)

Implemented on the [`with` branch](https://github.com/open-flash/rust-scoped-gc/blob/with/scoped-gc/src/gc_scope.rs)

Another idea was to not let the user create a `GcScope` manually with `GcScope::new` but instead expose a function `GcScope::with(executor)` providing a reference to the `gc_scope`. The closure `executor` corresponds to the `gc_scope`. So far, it either prevents the use of external references or allows to leak data to external `Gc` variables (first and fourth properties).

Here is the alloc signature:

```
impl<'gc> GcScope<'gc> {
    // ...
    pub fn alloc<T: Trace + 'gc>(&self, value: T) -> Result<Gc<'gc, T>, GcAllocErr> {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Here is a usage example showing the violation of the first property:

```
let message = GcScope::with(|scope| {
    scope
        .alloc(NamedObject {
            name: String::from("Hello, World!"),
        })
        .unwrap()
});
println!("{}", message.name);
```

### What I'd like

From what I understand, the `alloc` signature I'd like is:

```
impl<'gc> GcScope<'gc> {
    pub fn alloc<T: Trace + 'gc>(&'gc self, value: T) -> Result<Gc<'gc, T>, GcAllocErr> {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Where everything lives as long or longer than `self` (the `gc_scope`). But this blows up with the most simple tests:

```
fn test_gc() {
    let scope: GcScope = GcScope::new();
    scope.alloc(String::from("Hello, World!")).unwrap();
}
```

causes

```
error[E0597]: `scope` does not live long enough
  --> src/test.rs:50:3
   |
50 |   scope.alloc(String::from("Hello, World!")).unwrap();
   |   ^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
51 | }
   | - `scope` dropped here while still borrowed
   |
   = note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are created
```

I have no idea what happens here. [Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a8ccbd120c5f99464346c5f20ec188f4&version=nightly)

**Edit**: As explained to me on IRC, this is because I implement `Drop` which requires `&mut self`, but the `scope` is already borrowed in read-only mode.

## Overview

Here is a quick overview of the main components of my library.
[`GcScope`](https://github.com/open-flash/rust-scoped-gc/blob/auto-lifetime/scoped-gc/src/gc_scope.rs) contains a `RefCell` to its mutable state. This was introduced to not require `&mut self` for `alloc` because it "locked" the gc_scope and violated property 3: allocate multiple values.
This mutable state is [`GcState`](https://github.com/open-flash/rust-scoped-gc/blob/auto-lifetime/scoped-gc/src/gc_state.rs). It keeps track of all the allocated values. The values are stored as a forward-only linked list of [`GcBox`](https://github.com/open-flash/rust-scoped-gc/blob/auto-lifetime/scoped-gc/src/gc_box.rs). This `GcBox` is heap-allocated and contains the actual value with some metadata (how many active `Gc` pointers have it as their root and a boolean flag used to check if the value is reachable from the root (see [rust-gc](https://github.com/Manishearth/rust-gc)). The value here must outlive its `gc_scope` so `GcBox` uses a lifetime, and in turn `GcState` must then use a lifetime as well as `GcScope`: this is always the same lifetime meaning "longer than `gc_scope`". The fact that `GcScope` has a `RefCell` (interior mutability) and lifetime is maybe the reason why I can't get my lifetimes to work (it causes invariance?).

[`Gc`](https://github.com/open-flash/rust-scoped-gc/blob/auto-lifetime/scoped-gc/src/gc.rs) is a smart pointer to some `gc_scope`-allocated data. You can only get it through `gc_scope.alloc` or by cloning it.
[`GcRefCell`](https://github.com/open-flash/rust-scoped-gc/blob/auto-lifetime/scoped-gc/src/gc_ref_cell.rs) is most likely fine, it's just a `RefCell` wrapper adding metadata and behavior to properly support borrows.

## Flexibility

I'm fine with the following requirements to get a solution:

- unsafe code
- nightly features
- API changes (see for example my `with` approach). What matters is that I can create a temporary zone where I can manipulate garbage-collected values and that they are all dropped after this. These garbage-collected values need to be able to access longer-lived (but not static) variables outside of the scope.

[The repository](https://github.com/open-flash/rust-scoped-gc/tree/auto-lifetime) has a few tests in `scoped-gc/src/lib.rs` (compile-fail) as `scoped-gc/src/test.rs`.

**I found a solution, I'll post it once redacted.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of the hardest problems I had with lifetimes with Rust so far, but I managed to find a solution. Thank you to panicbit and mbrubeck for having helped me on IRC.

What helped me to move forward was the explanation of the error I posted at the end of my question:

```
error[E0597]: `scope` does not live long enough
  --> src/test.rs:50:3
   |
50 |   scope.alloc(String::from("Hello, World!")).unwrap();
   |   ^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
51 | }
   | - `scope` dropped here while still borrowed
   |
   = note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are created
```

I did not understand this error because it wasn't clear to me why `scope` was borrowed, for how long, or why it needs to no longer be borrowed at the end of the scope.

The reason is that during the allocation of the value, the `scope` is immutably borrowed for the duration of the allocated value. The issue now is that the scope contains a state object that implements "Drop": **custom implementations of `drop` use `&mut self`** -> it is not possible to get a mutable borrow for the drop while the value is already immutably borrowed.

Understanding that drop requires `&mut self` and that it is incompatible with immutable borrows unlocked the situation.

It turns out that the inner-outer approach described in the question above had the correct lifetimes with `alloc`:

```
impl<'outer> GcScope<'outer> {
    // ...

    pub fn alloc<'inner, T: Trace + 'outer>(
        &'inner self,
        value: T,
    ) -> Result<Gc<'inner, T>, GcAllocErr> {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

The returned `Gc` lives as long as `GcScope` and the allocated values must live longer than the current `GcScope`. As mentioned in the question, the issue with this solution is that it did not support circular values.

The circular values failed to work not because of the lifetimes of `alloc` but due to the custom `drop`. Removing `drop` allowed all the tests to pass (but leaked memory).

The explanation is quite interesting:

The lifetime of `alloc` expresses the properties of the allocated values. The allocated values cannot outlive their `GcScope` but their content must live as long or longer than `GcScope`. When creating a cycle, the value is subject to both of these constraints: it is allocated so must live as long or shorter than `GcScope` but also referenced by another allocated value so it must live as long or longer than `GcScope`. Because of this there is only one solution: the allocated value must live **exactly as long** as its scope.

It means that the lifetime of `GcScope` and its allocated values is exactly the same. **When two lifetimes are the same, Rust does not guarantee the order of the drops**. The reason why this happens is that the `drop` implementations could try to access each other and since there's no ordering it would be unsafe (the value might already have been freed).

This is explained in the [Drop Check chapter of the Rustonomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/dropck.html).

In our case, the `drop` implementation of the state of the garbage collected does not dereference the allocated values (quite the opposite, it frees their memory) so the Rust compiler is overly cautious by preventing us from implementing `drop`.

Fortunately, the Nomicon also explains how to work around these check of values with the same lifetimes. The solution is to use the `may_dangle` attribute on the lifetime parameter of the `Drop` implementation.
This is as unstable attribute that requires to enable the `generic_param_attrs` and `dropck_eyepatch` features.

Concretely, my `drop` implementation became:

```
unsafe impl<'gc> Drop for GcState<'gc> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        // Free all the values allocated in this scope
        // Might require changes to make sure there's no use after free
    }
}
```

And I added the following lines to `lib.rs`:

```
#![feature(generic_param_attrs)]
#![feature(dropck_eyepatch)]
```

You can read more about these features:

- [`generic_param_attrs`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/48848)
- [`may_dangle`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/34761)

I updated my library [scoped-gc](https://github.com/open-flash/rust-scoped-gc) with the fix for this issue if you want to take a closer look at it.